# Function two variables, integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Could you explain to me how to solve this exercise?
$$f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$f(x,y) =  \begin{cases} 1, \ \ \ \ \ \text{for}  \ x \ge 0, \ x \le y < x+1 \\ -1, \  \ \text{for} \ x \ge 0, \ x+1 \le y<x+2 \\ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

How to compute $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dx \right)dy?$$

Comment: Draw a picture of where $f(x,y) = 1$ and where $f(x,y) = -1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi_y(x) = f(x,y) $. Then $\phi_y(x) =1$ when $x \ge 0$ and $y-1 < x \le y$,
$\phi_y(x) =-1$ when $x \ge 0$ and $y-2 < x \le y-1$ and zero otherwise.

[image]

Hence if $y<0$, we have $\phi_y(x) =0$.

If $y \in [0,1)$, we have $\phi_y(x) =1$ when $x \in (0,y]$, and $0$ otherwise.

If $y \in [1,2)$, we have $\phi_y(x) =-1$ when $x \in (0,y-1]$, $\phi_y(x) =1$ when $x \in (y-1,y]$, and $0$ otherwise.

If $y \ge 2$, we have $\phi_y(x) =-1$ when $x \in (y-2,y-1]$, $\phi_y(x) =1$ when $x \in (y-1,y]$, and $0$ otherwise.

Now compute $\int_\mathbb{R} \phi_y(x) dx$ for each of these four cases. Then integrate the result.

Comment: So for $y \ \in [0,1)$ I get $\int_0^y dx = y$, for $y \in [1,2)$ I get $\int_0^{y-1}-dx + \int_{y-1}^ydx=1-y+y-y+1=2-y$ and for $y \ge 2$ $\int_{y-2}^{y-1} -dx + \int_{y-1}^ydx = -y+1+y-2+y-y+1=0 $. Then I integrate $\int_0^1ydy+ \int_1^2 (2-y)dy = 0,5+0,5=1$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Hagrid: Yes, looks good.

Comment: @Hagrid: You are very welcome.

Comment: I have one more question. What would change if I wanted to integrate $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dy)dx$? It can't be $\int_0^{\infty}(\int_x^{x+1}dy)dx + \int_0^{\infty}(\int_{x+1}^{x+2}dy)dx$ but I don't see how to split $[0, \infty)$ for $x$, like you did above for $y$.

Comment: No, it is even simpler, look at the picture. Basically $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) dy = 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Start with drawing the sets

$A= \{ (x,y) \colon x \geq 0 \ \& \ x \leq y < x+1\}$,
$B= \{ (x,y) \colon x \geq 0 \ \& \ x+1 \leq y < x+2\}$
to get the integration limits.

Now, observe that

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} (\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dx)dy$
$= \underbrace{\int_{1}^{\infty} \left(\int_{y-1}^{y} dx\right) dy + \int_{0}^{1} \left( \int_{0}^{y} dx \right) dy}_{\mathrm{integration \ over \ a\  set } A} + \underbrace{\int_{2}^{\infty} \left(\int_{y-2}^{y-1} (-1)dx\right) dy + \int_{1}^{2} \left( \int_{0}^{y-1} (-1)dx \right) dy}_{\mathrm{dintegration \ over \ a\  set } B} $

Now, calculate.

Comment: Isn't the solution $0$?

Comment: I don't think so, write your calculations here. It is not very complicated to calculate this.

Comment: Well, $\int_{y-1}^y dx = y-y+1=1$ and $\int_1^{\infty}dy= \infty$. Next, $\int_0^ydx=y$ and $\int_0^1ydy=0,5$. Then $\int_{y-2}^{y-1}-dx=-y+1+y-2=-1$ and $\int_2^{\infty}-dy= - \infty$. And $\int_0^{y-1}-dx = 1-y$ and $\int_1^2 (1-y)dy=-0,5$? Could you tell me where I make the mistake?

Comment: $\infty - \infty$ is indeterminate, note that $\int_{1}^{\infty} dy - \int_{2}^{\infty} dy = \int_{1}^{2}dy$, since $\int_{a}^{b}= \int_{a}^{a_0} + \int_{a_0}^{b}$, for $a \leq a_0 \leq b$. Now, you should get the correct result.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The solution is $\int_1^2 dy = 2-1=1$, indeed. Thank you. And I'm sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 2):

I learned a really elegant way of doing this stuff from an old German analyst whose advisor's advisor was Hilbert. (He had interesting stories.) He used characteristic functions to avoid drawing any pictures. For example, your function is
$$
   f(x,y)=\chi_{[0,1)}(y-x)\chi_{[0,\infty]}(x)-\chi_{[1,2)}(y-x)\chi_{[0,\infty]}(x).
$$
You can see that $f=1$ if $0 \le y-x < 1$ and $x \ge 0$, etc.
Now the regions tend to take care of themselves. This is particularly useful when you try to swap orders of integration, and you want to avoid pictures and the errors that go with my bad pictures. In this case,
$$
\begin{align}
    & \int\left(\int f(x,y)dx\right)dy = \\
    & = \int\left(\int\left[\chi_{[0,1]}(y-x)-\chi_{[1,2]}(y-x)\right]\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)\,dx\right)dy \\
    & = \int\left(\int_{y}^{y+1}\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)\,dx-\int_{y}^{y+2}\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)\,dx\right)dy
\end{align}
$$
Now I think you can see what is going on, if I haven't made an error.